# Link PostgreSQL to MS Access using ADO library via ODBC driver (DSN-less)

Tags: vba, postgresql, ms-access, odbc, ado

Hello :) I've searched Stackoverflow and Google for a lot of hours and would like to have a clear answer to my problem, because I got a little bit confused. I want to link a table from my PostgreSQL database to my MS Access frontend using VBA. Therefore I'm using the ADO library and installed the 32 bit ODBC driver for PostgreSQL. It works great if I use a connection string with a defined DSN, code looks like this:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnect As String
strConnect = "DSN=PostgreSQL35W;Database=...;UID=...;PWD=..."
conn.Open
```

But the thing is that I dont wan't to use a connection string with DSN, because I dont want to mess around with these DSNs, esspecially not in a distributed environment. Therefore I would like to use a **DSN-less** connection string. But it seems like that the ADO library doesn't support DSN-less connection strings while using the ODBC driver for PostgreSQL. Is that true?

Here's the code I used for the DSN-less connection:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnect As String
strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=...;Port=5432;Database=...;UID=...;PWD=..;TABLE=...
```

I know there are a lot of threads about that topic, but I couldn't get a clear answer for it. So thank you very much in advance!

Comment: When connecting using ADO, you don't need `ODBC;`. That's a DAO thing.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much, it works now.